# how can i reference something in the /values/strings.xml file programatically?

Tags: android, xml, string

i had some items in my strings.xml file that i want to change programatically, and originally i was doing it through a `setText();`call but now i am attempting to translate my app to a different language which means everything needs to be set in my strings.xml file.  is it possible to put all the text for my app into a strings.xml and change things programatically through references to the string names, instead of using the setText() function call?  for example how would i reference "GrandTotal"?

```
<string name="GrandTotal">Grand Total:</string>
<string name="choose_prompt">Choose a Mode</string>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `setText(R.string.GrandTotal);`

If you don't have the possibility to set the text via `resId` directly you can use [`getString(R.string.GrandTotal);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29)

Comment: how do you do the same from within a static method, I can't access getString in a static method. :-\

Answer (score 6):

To avoid confusion between resourceIds and real ints, you could also use statements like

```
String s = getResources().getString( R.string.grand_total );
```

but for most ui methods an overload often provides support for passing directly resourceIds as @Keyboardsurfer said

Comment: thanks, both of the items that you and keyboardsurfer provided helped to be the fix for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way . I hope it helps you .

```
setText(getResources().getString(R.string.GrandTotal));
```

Answer (score 0):

in an Acrivity:

```
String str = getString(R.string.choose_prompt);
```

or

```
String str = this.getString(R.string.choose_prompt);
```